# Get an instance of a persistent object, given the identifier in string

Tags: delphi, runtime

In Delphi 7, how to get an instance of a persistent object, given the object identifier in string?

```
function TForm1.GetObject(Identifier: string): TPersistent;
begin
  //what to do here?
end;
```

Example of use:

```
//If I have these declared...
public
  MyString: string;
  MyStringList: TStringList;

//the function will be used something like this
MyString:=TStringList(GetObject('MyStringList')).Text;
```

Thank you in advance and please apologize me for not being able to express my question clearly in English.

Answer (score 2):

This is very common.
You need to hold a list of the object instances by name. You've already suggested this with your string list. This can be used to retrieve the instance by name. So:
When you create your object you do:

```
MyObjList := TStringList.Create;

MyObj := TMyObj.Create;
MyObjList.AddObject( 'Thing', MyObj );

MyObj2 := TMyObj.Create;
MyObjList.AddObject( 'Thing2', MyObj2 );
```

etc.

Now, to retrieve you simply do:

```
function GetObject( const AName : string ) : TMyObj;
begin
  I := MyObjList.IndexOf( AName );
  If I = -1 then
    Raise Exception.Create( 'Cant find it' );
  Result := MyObjList[I] as TMyObj;
end;
```

Bri

Answer (score 1):

You could create a published property, which could be accessed via runtime type information (RTTI). See p.73 of [Delphi in a nutshell](http://books.google.com/books?id=vLk522pMxlsC&pg=PA73&dq=published+delphi+directive&ei=PDd5SoS1EaP8yAS8w-zJDA#v=onepage&q=published%20delphi%20directive&f=false) and [GetObjectProp](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/typinfo/getobjectprop.html).

```
Writeln((GetObjectProp(O,'ObjField') As TNamedObject).ObjectName);
```